# MNIST Deep Neural Network using TensorFlow

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow

I have been working on this code for a while and it gave me a lot of headache before I got it to work. It basically tries to use the mnist dataset to classify handwritten digits. I am not using the prepackaged mnist in TensorFlow because I want to learn preprocessing the data myself and for deeper understanding of TensorFlow.

Its finally working but I would love it if someone with expertise could take a look at it and tell me what they think and if the results its producing are actually real stats or if its overfitting or not learning at all.

It's giving me accuracy between 83% and 91% from the test dataset.

the dataset I'm using is from https://pjreddie.com/projects/mnist-in-csv/ basically the two links on top of the page.

here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()
from sklearn import preprocessing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # lets load the file
    train_file = 'mnist_train.csv'
    test_file = 'mnist_test.csv'
    #train_file = 'mnist_train_small.csv'
    #test_file = 'mnist_test_small.csv'

    train = np.loadtxt(train_file, delimiter=',')
    test = np.loadtxt(test_file, delimiter=',')

    x_train = train[:,1:785]
    y_train = train[:,:1]

    x_test = test[:,1:785]
    y_test = test[:,:1]
    print(x_test.shape)

    # lets normalize the data
    def normalize(input_data):
        minimum = input_data.min(axis=0)
        maximum = input_data.max(axis=0)
        #normalized = (input_data - minimum) / ( maximum - minimum )
        normalized = preprocessing.normalize(input_data, norm='l2')
        return normalized

    # convert to a onehot array 
    def one_hot(input_data):
        one_hot = []
        for item in input_data:
            if item == 0.:
                one_h = [1.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.]
            elif item == 1.:
                one_h = [0.,1.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.]
            elif item == 2.:
                one_h = [0.,0.,1.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.]
            elif item == 3.:
                one_h = [0.,0.,0.,1.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.]
            elif item == 4.:
                one_h = [0.,0.,0.,0.,1.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.]
            elif item == 5.:
                one_h = [0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,1.,0.,0.,0.,0.]
            elif item == 6.:
                one_h = [0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,1.,0.,0.,0.]
            elif item == 7.:
                one_h = [0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,1.,0.,0.]
            elif item == 8.:
                one_h = [0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,1.,0.]
            elif item == 9.:
                one_h = [0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,1.]

            one_hot.append(one_h)
        one_hot = np.array(one_hot)
        #one_hot = one_hot.reshape(len(one_hot),10,1)
        #one_hot = one_hot.reshape(len(one_hot), 7,1)
        #return tf.constant([one_hot])
        return one_hot
    def one_hot_tf(val):
        indices = val
        depth = 10
        on_value = 1.0
        off_value = 0.0
        axis = -1
        oh = tf.one_hot(indices, depth,
                   on_value=on_value, off_value=off_value,
                   axis=axis, dtype=tf.float32,
                   name='ONEHOT')
        return (oh)
    x_train = normalize(x_train)
    x_test =  normalize(x_test)
    #    x_train = sess.run(tf.convert_to_tensor(x_train))
    #    x_test =  sess.run(tf.convert_to_tensor(x_test))

    '''
    data_initializer = tf.placeholder(dtype=x_train.dtype,
                                        shape=x_train.shape)
    label_initializer = tf.placeholder(dtype=x_test.dtype,
                                         shape=x_test.shape)
    x_train= sess.run(tf.Variable(data_initializer, trainable=False, collections=[]))
    x_test = sess.run(tf.Variable(label_initializer, trainable=False, collections=[]))
    '''


    y_test =  one_hot(y_test)
    y_train =  one_hot(y_train)
    print(y_test[:5])
    #   y_test =  sess.run(one_hot_tf(y_test))
    #   y_train =  sess.run(one_hot_tf(y_train))


    # define the parameters
    input_nodes = 784
    output_nodes = 10
    hl1_nodes = 500
    hl2_nodes = 500
    hl3_nodes = 500
    epochs = 10
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, input_nodes])
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

    # graphing
    loss_rate = []


    def nn(data):
        layer1 = {'w':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([input_nodes, hl1_nodes])),
                  'b':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hl1_nodes]))}
        layer2 = {'w':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hl1_nodes, hl2_nodes])),
                  'b':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hl2_nodes]))}
        layer3 = {'w':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hl2_nodes, hl3_nodes])),
                  'b':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hl3_nodes]))}
        output_layer = {'w':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hl3_nodes, output_nodes])),
                  'b':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([output_nodes]))}

        l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, layer1['w']), layer1['b'])
        l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

        l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1, layer2['w']), layer2['b'])
        l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)

        l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2, layer3['w']), layer3['b'])
        l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)

        output = tf.add(tf.matmul(l3, output_layer['w']), output_layer['b'])

        return(output)


    def train(x):
        prediction = nn(x)
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=y))
        optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001).minimize(loss)

        init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        sess.run(init)

        for epoch in range(epochs):
            epochloss = 0
            batch_size = 10
            batches = 0
            for batch in range(int(len(x_train)/batch_size)):
                next_batch = batches+batch
                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict={x:x_train[batches:next_batch, :], y:y_train[batches:next_batch, :]})
                epochloss = epochloss + c
                batches += batch
                loss_rate.append(c)

            print("Epoch ", epoch, " / ", epochs, " - Loss ", epochloss)

        correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, tf.float32))
        print("Accuracy : ", accuracy.eval({x:x_test, y:y_test}))


    train(x)

    plt.plot(loss_rate)
    plt.show()
```

The output of 3 different runs are:

```
=========== RESTART: /Users/macbookpro/Desktop/AI/tf/OWN/test3.py ===========
(10000, 784)
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
Epoch  0  /  5  - Loss  nan
Epoch  1  /  5  - Loss  nan
Epoch  2  /  5  - Loss  nan
Epoch  3  /  5  - Loss  nan
Epoch  4  /  5  - Loss  nan
Accuracy :  0.9053

=========== RESTART: /Users/macbookpro/Desktop/AI/tf/OWN/test3.py ===========
(10000, 784)
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
Epoch  0  /  5  - Loss  nan
Epoch  1  /  5  - Loss  nan
Epoch  2  /  5  - Loss  nan
Epoch  3  /  5  - Loss  nan
Epoch  4  /  5  - Loss  nan
Accuracy :  0.8342

=========== RESTART: /Users/macbookpro/Desktop/AI/tf/OWN/test3.py ===========
(10000, 784)
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
Epoch  0  /  5  - Loss  nan
Epoch  1  /  5  - Loss  nan
Epoch  2  /  5  - Loss  nan
Epoch  3  /  5  - Loss  nan
Epoch  4  /  5  - Loss  nan
Accuracy :  0.9
```

---Update---
I found the answer in rewriting the code as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

sess = tf.Session()

file = "mnist_train.csv"
data = np.loadtxt(file, delimiter=',')


y_vals = data[:,0:1]
x_vals = data[:,1:785]

seed = 3
tf.set_random_seed(seed)
np.random.seed(seed)
batch_size = 90

# split into 80/20 datasets, normalize between 0:1 with min max scaling
train_indices = np.random.choice(len(x_vals), round(len(x_vals)*0.8), replace=False)
# up there we chose randomly 80% of the data
test_indices = np.array(list(set(range(len(x_vals))) - set(train_indices)))
# up we chose the remaining 20% 
print(test_indices)

x_vals_train = x_vals[train_indices]
x_vals_test = x_vals[test_indices]
y_vals_train = y_vals[train_indices]
y_vals_test = y_vals[test_indices]

def normalize_cols(m):
    col_max = m.max(axis=0)
    col_min = m.min(axis=0)
    return (m-col_min)/(col_max - col_min)
x_vals_train = np.nan_to_num(normalize_cols(x_vals_train))
x_vals_test = np.nan_to_num(normalize_cols(x_vals_test))

# function that initializes the weights and the biases 
def init_weight(shape, std_dev):
    weight = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape, stddev=std_dev))
    return(weight)

def init_bias(shape, std_dev):
    bias= tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape, stddev=std_dev))
    return(bias)

# initialize placeholders. 
x_data = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 784], dtype=tf.float32)
y_target = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 1], dtype=tf.float32)


# the fully connected layer will be used three times for all three hidden layers
def fully_connected(input_layer, weights, biases):
    layer = tf.add(tf.matmul(input_layer, weights), biases)
    return (tf.nn.relu(layer))

# Now create the model for each layer and the output layer.
# we will initialize a weight matrix, bias matrix and the fully connected layer
# for this, we will use hidden layers of size 500, 500, and 10

'''
This will mean many variables variables to fit. This is because between the data and the first hidden layer we have 
784*500+500 = 392,500 variables to change.
continuing this way we will have end up with how many variables we have overall to fit
'''

# create first layer (500 hidden nodes)
weight_1 = init_weight(shape=[784,500], std_dev=10.0)
bias_1 = init_bias(shape=[500], std_dev=10.0)
layer_1 = fully_connected(x_data, weight_1, bias_1)

# create second layer (5-- hidden nodes)
weight_2 = init_weight(shape=[500,500], std_dev=10.0)
bias_2 = init_bias(shape=[500], std_dev=10.0)
layer_2 = fully_connected(layer_1, weight_2, bias_2)

# create third layer (10 hidden nodes)
weight_3 = init_weight(shape=[500,10], std_dev=10.0)
bias_3 = init_bias(shape=[10], std_dev=10.0)
layer_3 = fully_connected(layer_2, weight_3, bias_3)

# create output layer (1 output value)
weight_4 = init_weight(shape=[10,1], std_dev=10.0)
bias_4 = init_bias(shape=[1], std_dev=10.0)
final_output = fully_connected(layer_3, weight_4, bias_4)


# define the loss function and the optimizer and initializing the model
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(y_target - final_output))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.05)
train_step = optimizer.minimize(loss)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

# we will now train our model 10 times, store train and test los, select a random batch size, 
# and print the status every 1 generation

# initalize the loss vectors
loss_vec = []
test_loss = []
for i in range(10):
    # choose random indices for batch selection
    rand_index = np.random.choice(len(x_vals_train), size=batch_size)
    # get random batch
    rand_x = x_vals_train[rand_index]
    #rand_y = np.transpose(y_vals_train[rand_index])
    rand_y = y_vals_train[rand_index] #???????????
    # run the training step
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x_data: rand_x, y_target: rand_y})
    # get and store train loss
    temp_loss = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={x_data:rand_x, y_target:rand_y})
    loss_vec.append(temp_loss)
    # get and store test loss 
    #test_temp_loss = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={x_data:x_vals_test, y_target:np.transpose([y_vals_test])})
    test_temp_loss = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={x_data:x_vals_test, y_target:y_vals_test}) #???????
    test_loss.append(test_temp_loss)
    if(i+1) %1==0:
        print('Generation: '+str(i+1)+". Loss = "+str(temp_loss))

plt.plot(loss_vec, 'k-', label='Train Loss')
plt.plot(test_loss, 'r--', label='Test Loss')
plt.title('Loss Per generation ')
plt.xlabel('Generation')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

I commented most of it just so if someone stumbles here and needs some help they can understand whats going on.

Comment: I think I've seen this question somewhere else...

Comment: @StudentT Yes I asked it in codereview but no one answered so i thought i would come here hoping to find someone to take a look at it and tell me. Speaking of, I am now sure something is wrong so i will probably work on it and post the answer and remove the duplicates.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/159660/65105

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you have such high error on the test set and have so many hidden layers/nodes, it's quite possible that your model is overfitting. Try using dropout or weight decay to regularize the weights of your network.

Comment: Thanks a lot @liangjy I appreciate your comment and that sounds very true. I tried replicating the same code but without trying to format the data just like the tutorial in tensorflow.org and it worked out well. I will keep your advice in case I fall into the same problem again.